# Рекурсия на языке программирования С++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

```
void per(int n)
{
    if(n>=2)
    return per(n/2);
    cout<<n%2;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    per(n);
    return 0;
}
```

не понимаю почему не работает бинарный перевод, буду рад за ответ

Comment: void per(int n)
{
 if(n>=2)
 return per(n/2);
 cout<<n%2;
 
}

int main()
{
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 per(n);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Может я чего не понимаю))) Зачем в VOID используется return per(n/2);?

Comment: @iksuy это было моя синтаксическая ошибка ) я знал но забыл случайно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что он стоит уже после return - после выхода из функции.

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался самостоятельно. После `return` он завершает функцию... Похоже очень часто использую int, чем void.

Comment: да... очень часто